# BIRT 4.3.2 - embedded background image is not appearing in pdf report

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT 4.3.2 for HTML and PDF report generation.

My requirement is to add text over image for both HTML and PDF reports. I have achieved this by for HTML report, but unsuccessful for pdf report. Please help.

I did the below and its working for HTML report

1. Create a grid with one row-->cell add background image(URI based)
2. Inserted a grid of one row-->cell on the previous cell(Step 1) and add text element

Background image is appearing on the HTML report.

I did the below for PDF report.

1. Create a grid with one row-->cell add background image(embed)
2. Inserted a grid of one row-->cell on the previous cell(Step 1) and add text element

Background image is **NOT** appearing on the PDF report. Please help.

Thanks,
Veera

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the image in your resource folder. Then apply a new style to the grid cell, choose background, then select the image from your resource folder.

Then your HTML and PDF exports will display the image.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried as suggested, but still there is no image in the exported PDF report. Please help

Comment: Here are the steps I followed.

1. new report
2. add grid 3x3
3. select a cell, right click and select Style > New Style
4. select background
5. select browse
6. select resources
7. import the png file (or do this first and import / drag and drop to the resources folder)
8. select the PNG
9. choose OK
10. add something else to the same cell, like text, it is on top
11. preview
12. render to PDF

Comment: Thank You very much for the help. I tried your steps, it worked within the eclipse context(or untill preview).But not in web application context.
As per my understanding(though I am new bee) I think the recommended way is to embed the image within the report for PDF and for HTML specify URI path.

Comment: Below is what I tried. But still no luck. 
 1. new report 
 2. Outline go to Embedded Images and added myCustom.png
 2. add grid 1x1 . select a cell, 
 3. Under properties tab go to Advanced-->Background Image set the value to "myCustom.png"
 4. Advanced-->Background Image Type set the value to Embedded Image
 5. Added text element
 6. Deployed the report in server and tested.

Comment: <grid id="880">
            <row id="882">
                <property name="height">3.7835416666666664cm</property>
                <cell id="883">
                    <property name="backgroundImage">myCustom.png</property>
                    <property name="backgroundImageType">embed</property>
                    <text id="886"/>
                </cell>
            </row>
        </grid>